# Linux | Copy only top 100 new files in directory and nested directories

Tags: command-line

I have storage something like below on AzureVM/Ubuntu

```
-/A
   -/B --> 10000 log files
   -/C --> 100000 log files 
      -/D --> 200000 images 
   summary.xml
   -/data --> 1000 csv files
```

Now because data size is very big to compute and do any operation there I want to take a sample of this data to develop my data analysis code.

I want to copy a subset to a different location which has the 100 newest files in each directory and nested directory and all the files on the root something like this.

```
-/New_Location
   -/B --> 100 log files
   -/C --> 100 log files 
       -/D --> 100 images 
   summary.xml
   -/data --> 100 csv files
```

I tried multiple commands based on cp but nothing is working for me and taking too much time to execute.

Can someone please help me here?

Comment: What commands? Lets see exactly what you have tried. How can anyone help you if you do not give the info.

Comment: one of things i tried, going to each folder and then run this command cp -R  -- *([1,100]) ../New, but it is not copying all nested folders data, also too much manual work as I have thousands of folders within one

Comment: Additional info in the question please not as a comment. You said one of the things what were the rest?

Answer (score 0):

You can usually divide this into three tasks, where you start with the directory structure and next, as in your case, limit files to 100. The last part inverts the *match* to scope up the rest of the files.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash  
  
# Example START  
[[ ! -d A/ ]] && { \  
mkdir -p \  
A/{tmp/folder,\  
{A..Z}}/{images,data} && \  
printf %s\\0 \  
A/{summary.xml,\  
tmp/De5Loh4X.tmp,\  
{A..Z}/{{1..1000}_file.log,\  
images/{1..1000}_pic.{jpg,png},\  
data/example.csv}} | xargs -0 touch; }  
### Example END  
  
set -o noglob  
  
source=A  
target=target  
number=100  
# prune="-false"  
prune="-type d -path $source/tmp -prune"  
match='-name *.log -o -name *.jpg -o -name *.png'  
  
echo Create directory structure.  
find "$source" \  
\( $prune -o -type d -links 2 \) -printf %P\\0 | cpio -0 -pvdm -D "$source" "$target"  
  
  
echo Copy 100 files.  
while IFS= read -rd ''; do  
find "$REPLY" \  
-maxdepth 1 -type f \( $match \) -printf '%T@\t%P\0' | sort -zk1rn | cut -zf2- | head -zn $number | cpio -0 -pvdm -D "$REPLY" "$target/${REPLY/#$source\//}"  
done < <( \  
find "$source" \  
\( $prune -false -o -type f \) -printf %h\\0 | sort -zu \  
)  
  
echo Copy everything else.  
find "$source" \  
\( $prune -false -o -type f ! \( $match \) \) -printf %P\\0 | cpio -0 -pvdm -D "$source" "$target"
```

Comment: `-name *` will limit all file types to 100

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done by selective archiving.
You can tarball the files (only the intended ones) and then extract the tarball somewhere else.
I am assuming that your log files have the same name except for the numbering (e.g. log1, log2 etc). So the first hundred files can be defined in tarball command as log{1..100}.
For example:

`tar -cvf copied.tar <path1>/log{1..100} <path2>/log({1..100}` etc

When you extract, the original file structure will be recreated in the new location. So you may need to use "--strip-components=" option to truncate the redundant leading directories to avoid clutter.